# Enter Values in Label By Text-filed and create Nodes in Loops - Form Maker

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter link description here](https://mobulous.app/ajeetformgenerator/getform.html)

Hello I Have Modified some JavaScript in the function created labelFunction()

you can found it inside form.js  ,

I am trying to get the value of text-field and print inside the new label node created under Your Dynamic Form Section, but i am stuck in the JavaScript logic because the node is created but they are repeating the text field value again and again but i want each label with different value. See screens below:-

[image]
[image]

Help me to solve this logic demo link given below:-
https://mobulous.app/ajeetformgenerator/getform.html

Answer (score 0):

Need some more useful informatin,cannot understand your problem

Comment: I Have Edited The Question Please Read It Again, Hope This time yo could help me

Answer (score 0):

inside the jquery,if button is the class of get text box value and body is the id of body

```
     $("#body").on("click", ".button", function () {
                            var inputText = $("#name").val();
                            $("#dynName").val(inputText);
});
```

assign a variable 'inputText' that will store the content in the textfeild box.'name' is the id of get text box value. 
'inputText' is the id of textfeild .
'dynName' is the id of dynamic forms text feild.